# Getting an iPhone off wifi

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi

I'm in the process of testing routerequipment, and in that test i'd like to control wireless devices, so that they simulate leaving the area.

On android I have created a small app that receives commands (e.g. watch this on netflix, turn wifi off, browse to this page), to simulate user activity. Though this is great, it's not possible (maybe it is, but I have no iOS development skills, and my research tells me that it's almost impossible to automate, espeacially things as wifi, on iOS, unless you jailbreak it, and use private SDK's).

So my question here is more of a way to get ideas. Does anybody have any idea how to automaticly turn wifi off an iphone to simulate it leaving the wifi coverage area?
Bear in mind that this needs to be automated somehow. The best thing I can think of now is simply cutting the power to the iphone, and turning it back on and let the iPhone boot. Another solution, rather wicked, would be a small model-train leaving the wifi-coverage with the iPhone - haha, how awesome would that be!

Another thing I've tried is jamming by sending deauth-signals to the iPhone. While that works, it does not automaticly log back on the wifi, unless you manually lock and unlock the iphone. It would have been a great and simple solution, but it doesn't work.

I really hope somebody here has a great idea :)

have a great day! :)

/Benjamin

Comment: Have you tried using the **Network Link Conditioner** on your iPhone? You will have to enable developer settings to use it, but it will really helpful to simulate weak signals/2g/3g/4g etc. on your device without needing to get ChuChu Train. http://www.myuiviews.com/img/link-conditioner-3.png

Comment: Looks awesome! But:
a) Is this also working with wifi? 
b) If so - if it has a "Bad connection" doesn't it just simulate the bad connection upon the iPhone, and not actually losing the connection to the gateway?
c) My guess is, that this probably isn't allowed to be automated via code. :(